# How to deploy and install using single command

Tags: tomcat, deployment, maven

I have an application that is broken into four Flex modules:
1) Main module
2) Sub module 1
3) Sub module 2
3) Library project.

We have created this project in the maven way.When we try building the project using mvn install, it is getting built fine. The war file is getting generated and is available in the target folder.

I now have a requirement where in I need to also deploy the project to tomcat server. In order to achieve this I have made use of the tomcat-maven-plugin provided by codehaus mojo project. When I try to do a mvn tomcat:deploy, the build is failing.The build engine is not 
able to look up my library project.
If I try executing mvn tomcat:deploy-only, the war file that was generated when we did a mvn istall is getting deployed.

Can somebody help me out with this issue.

Maven version  used: 3.1
Flex mojos version used : 4.0-beta-7

Thanks,
Vennela

Comment: As per tomcat-maven-plugin documentation, "mvn tomcat:deploy" executes the tomcat deploy step after Maven package phase. To isolate the problem, you may want to try "mvn package" once to ensure it is also not failing.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the tomcat-maven-plugin executes the deploy after maven package phase.

Since deploying is pretty much another word for copying, you could also use the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/index.html) (which you probably are already using) if you are having trouble with the tomcat plugin. For example:

```
</plugins>
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>

  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The above copies the war to outputDirectory and exploded war to webappDirectory, overriding the default paths (invoking eg. the command "mvn package")

Default way:

```
<project>
  ...
  <groupId>com.example.projects</groupId>
  <artifactId>documentedproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Documented Project</name>
  <url>http://example.com</url>
  ...
</project>
```

Hope it helps.